# Adding 'NOT IN' clause in native query using position parameters?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, java-ee-6

How to dynamically append `NOT IN` clause in native SQL query JPA,

```
public final String s =  "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN ?";
public final String e_not_in = "('a', 'b', 'c')";
```

in java code,

```
List<Employee>  el = getEm().createNativeQuery(s).setParameter(1, e_not_in);
```

But the resultant list has data related to `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`, Currently there are more than 200 queries in SQL constants which consume this constant dynamic parameter, Is there any workaround other than hard coding the `NOT IN` clause in each and every SQL query or changing position parameters to individual list items like `EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN (?1, ?2, ?3)` for `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`, As the issue is in production, needs to be solved immediately , Any solutions that would make the change immediately would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Those queries need to be changed by someone, what alternative do you have in mind?

Comment: "The issue is in production" : so nobody actually checked that before releasing? Using a String parameter is clearly never going to achieve what was the intent

Comment: Considered going back to JDBC if you are stuck at JPA1 ? I mean, get the JDBC Connection from EclipseLink then you can input a List presumably https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID NOT IN (?)");
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList();
ids.add(1L);
ids.add(2L);
query.setParameter(1, ids);
```

Updated:
Yes, I mean `createNativeQuery`.

Comment: `createNamedQuery`? You mean `createNativeQuery`. Otherwise, you're right. Though the parentheses around the question mark are not required, but are supported by Hibernate and I think EclipseLink.

Comment: My case is JPA 1.0, would not accept List in the set parameter.